# Designing a boost converter

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am looking to design a boost convertor for a high school project and after doing quite some research I have come up with the following design.

[image]

[image]

I am looking to double my voltage. (Input voltage will most probably be 9 volts)

The left part of the circuit is an astable multivibrator and the right part being the main circuit of the boost converter. I just wanted to know whether my circuit will actually work and the astable multivibrator will be successful in providing a switching frequency to short the circuit. I am no expert in electronics and could do with some help. Please mention the necessary changes I need to make if my circuit is glaringly wrong.

Comment: Your circuit diagram has the ground drawn in a weird way. And you need a base resistor for bj2. As it is now (see Andy's answer) you will probably blow up bj2 because the voltage you create is not limited.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I shall add a base resistor to limit the current to the transistor. Any other changes I need to make ?

Comment: Does it have to be an inductive boost converter? A capacitative booster is simpler and doesn't require a feedback circuit.

Comment: Since I have spent quite some time behind this thing, I don't really want to change it to a capacitive booster now unless I really have to.

Comment: You'll have to limit the output voltage in some way. The most simple (and least efficient!) way would be to add a zener diode over the output capacitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A boost converter works by storing energy and releasing it thousands of times per second. It stores energy in an inductor and this energy gets released into the load.

The amount of energy stored is proportional to the square of the current accumulated in the inductor over the 1st half of the switching cycle. So let's say you are operating at 50% duty cycle and you are storing 100 uJ. Let's also say your switching frequency is 100 kHz. From those two bits of information you can calculate power into the load because power = joules per second hence power is 10 watts.

If your load doesn't exactly take 10 watts then the output voltage will get bigger or get smaller until your output load does take 10 watts.

This is why a boost regulator needs a pretty good feedback control mechanism to cope with: -

1. Output load changes
2. Input voltage changes
3. Temperature related changes

In your circuit I see none of these things yet you have specifically said you want to double the voltage from input to output. How much of a discrepency can you therefore live with? You need to think about this and decide whether or not you are going to implement a closed loop controller to turn a thing that pushes out constant power to a thing that pushes out constant voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just need to illustrate the concept of how a boost cinvertor basically works and is not meant to be a well refined circuit. I do not intend to use this with another circuit. All i need is the voltage to increase across c2 (and want this increase to be visible on a multimeter) from my input voltage even if it has ripple or isn't of an exactly controlled value. Will my above circuit even work to just satisfy my above need ? What changes can I make to the above circuit to satisfy my above needs ?

Comment: @c0smicVorTeX Without a load, the voltage will simply increase until something breaks (eg, your capacitor becomes a short, or your diode burns out). If you add a resistor as load, the voltage will settle at whatever voltage is necessary to dissipate the input power across the resistor, which would give you a simple starting point.

Comment: So a resistor accross c2 should be added to prevent the circuit from blowing up ?

Comment: The best advice I can give you is get hold of LTSpice and simulate it. In fact, irrespective of you designing a booster,i would give that advice to anyone embarking on a design that would otherwise burn your fingers.

Comment: I shall simulate the circuit in it soon and come back here. Thank you !